# No me deja usar en condición ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: php, android, android-studio, json

buen día.

A la hora de programar un login con PHP y Mysql mediante Android Studio, me he encontrado con un problema, y es que tengo una variable pero no me permite usar ésta como condición, pero realmente tiene un valor pues al mostrarla con un toast funciona correctamente, de igual forma estoy comparando ambos valores de la condición con **equals**, entonces si alguien podría ayudarm, le agradecería muchísimo.

Mi código:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

            super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            String respuesta = "Test "+httpResponseMsg;

            if(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("Test correct")){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proceso exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(UserLoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(UserEmail,email);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this,httpResponseMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this,httpResponseMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
```

Muchas gracias, Camilo, por tu respuesta.

Mira, he intentado convertir el **httpResponseMsg** en int, para compararlo de forma directa con un ==, ya cambié en el php el valor a "1", pero al darle al botón de Inicio de sesión, me bota la aplicación.

Código:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

            super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            int respuesta = Integer.parseInt(httpResponseMsg);

            if(respuesta == 1){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proceso exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(UserLoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(UserEmail,email);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this,httpResponseMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this,httpResponseMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
```

¿Hice algo mal?

Comment: Estás destruyendo la actividad actual al invocar `finish()`. Si quitas esa línea debería funcionar. Si quieres cerrar la actividad actual una vez pasado el `Intent` debes colocar `finish()` después de `startActivity`, no antes.

Comment: Has probado con alguna otra variable? Es decir, es mejor trabajar en estos casos con enteros, ejemplo si registro entonces que tú script php envíe un 1 si no un 0, y haces un equals de nuevo, otra opción es que uses instaceof para comprobar que la respuesta que llega si es tipo string, puede quien la imprima bien en el Toast pero al comparar no lo haga, por ultiman alternativa, asegúrate de que no haya espacios en esa cadena de texto, usa un replace “ “, “” o un trim que elimina espacios al final de la cadena, Espero alguna de estas opciones te ayude

Comment: Kevin, el espacio que aparece abajo de la pregunta es **exclusivamente para respuestas**. Para agregar información nueva a la pregunta [la puedes editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/170318/edit). Para cuestiones breves, puedes comentar, en el hilo de comentarios de la pregunta. Conviene que seas más específico, ya que un simple: *Sigue sin funcionar :/. ¿Alguna otra cosa?*  da pocas pistas para poder ayudarte. Por ejemplo, ¿el código muestra el mensaje de este `Toast`: `                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proceso exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`?

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente para que entre a mostrar el `Toast` y realizar el `Intent`, el valor de `httpResponseMsg` debe ser "correct", no importando si es con mayusculas o minusculas, pero si no tiene este valor nunca entrará, debes asegurarte de recibir este valor.

```
     progressDialog.dismiss();
        String respuesta = "Test "+httpResponseMsg;  //httpResponseMsg debe ser "correct".

        if(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("Test correct")){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proceso exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(UserLoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(UserEmail,email);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this,httpResponseMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this,httpResponseMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Con respecto a tu edición, aquí el valor de `httpResponseMsg` debe ser numérico de otra forma marcara un error y probablemente se cierre tu aplicación, y para mostrar el `Toast` y realizar el `Intent` el valor de `httpResponseMsg` debe ser "1", este valor será convertido a entero mediante `Integer.parseInt()`.

```
  int respuesta = Integer.parseInt(httpResponseMsg);

            if(respuesta == 1){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proceso exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(UserLoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(UserEmail,email);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this,httpResponseMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(UserLoginActivity.this,httpResponseMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```